# Can/should we promote more use of the chat room?

Tags: discussion, beta, chat

Has anyone an opinion on whether chat room use can help a new SE site grow?  If it does make a difference, how can we encourage users to make use of the chat room?

Comment: I think the time has come to promote the chat more, seeing all the comments lately. I've opened a new [meta topic](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/191/use-our-chat-room), and also posted the chat FAQ in the chat room.

Answer (score 1):

**Give it some more time.**

At this stage (very very early beta), **we just haven't enough members yet,** and those that we have are spread apart across the globe's time zones and are perhaps not used to the SE engine, so very few people would ever find their way to the chat and find other members present just then.

The chat room is a great place to hang out if you're feeling like watching the world turn before your eyes. It can be very engaging and entertaining. I think there can be a need for, and a benefit from, the chat room in the long run. But we're not ready for that yet.