# Keep this site's chat room's name or change it?

Tags: discussion, chat

Chat rooms of other sites have oftentimes witty names, e. g. Interpersonal Skills has [The Awkward Silence](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/how-should-this-sites-general-chat-room-be-named), Academia got [The Ivory Tower](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/what-should-we-call-our-chat-room) and The Workplace offers its users [The Water Cooler](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114/what-should-the-name-of-our-chat-room-be).

On the one hand, renaming Parenting's chat room could increase its appeal (not so generic anymore, maybe a bit funny), on the other hand it may appear less serious.

So, is there interest in renaming the chat room or should it stay as it is?

<sub>I decided to not combine asking for suggestions - not renaming would then have been an answer *Parenting* - because it's probably easier to discuss it first in a separate post. After all, the site is pretty old and it was never renamed, so maybe there is no interest. In the past there seems to have been initiatives to [increase](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/can-should-we-promote-more-use-of-the-chat-room) [participation](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/use-our-chat-room). Renaming it may help, a bit.</sub>

---

### Update

**Thread to post / vote on suggestions: [How should Parenting's chat room be named?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/how-should-parentings-chat-room-be-named)**

Answer (score 5):

That's a great idea! I'm in favor.

Comment: I'm in favor as long as it's called The Timeout Corner

Answer (score -2):

In order to get a balanced view, vote this answer up if you don't like the idea.

Comment: I guess I'll vote it down, since I like the idea. Nice humor!