# How should Parenting's chat room be named?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

The [voting](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/keep-this-sites-chat-rooms-name-or-change-it) in the previous question was in favor of changing the name of Parenting's [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/parenting).

So now you can post suggestions for a new name and vote on them to choose the winner. There needn't be too many rules, probably just

- On topic in the widest sense, it should be related to Parenting
- Not rude or controversial

---

I'm not sure how long to keep the voting open, but I suggest that we take some time to choose a new name. No need to rush it. Let's give everyone the chance to participate, vote (and maybe change their vote).

---

In case you feel that the name shouldn't be changed, I suggest to write and answer suggesting the default name (*Parenting*) and if you have good reasons, write an answer over at [this question](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/keep-this-sites-chat-rooms-name-or-change-it) and link to it in the answer (or in a comment). But this is just a suggestion on how to possibly handle it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Playground**

A place to relax we regularly go to, where it’s easy to start a conversation with other parents and where we can also have fun.

Answer (score 2):

"Down the Rabbit Hole" or just "The Rabbit Hole", an allusion to Alice in Wonderland.

Pros:

- already a cultural phrase usually involving discussions that lead to other things.
- From a famous children's book

Cons: too cultural?

Answer (score 2):

### The Timeout Corner!

**Pros:**

- It's cool
- (Almost) everyone understands the reference
- It's highly relatable to the topic of parenting
- <s>You can tell people to "go to Timeout!" when you want to chat</s>
- Let me rephrase. How about we say "These comments are getting pretty heated. How about we take a timeout and go to The Timeout Corner to discuss."

**Cons:**

I honestly don't see any. At all.

The timeout corner is only a negative thing if you, as a parent, or we, as a community, make it a negative thing.

Comment: The only (small) con I can see here is that if someone new sees "go to Timeout!" and doesn't understand that is a chat room (or someone gets sent there while having a drawn out discussion / argument in the comments) it could be perceived as a punishment / negative thing.

Comment: @Becuzz I think in that case we can just say “let’s take it to chat”

Comment: Not too convinced. It has an undertone of “where you are sent to if you misbehave”.

Comment: @Stephie That's only if you solely use the timeout corner for misbehaving. I used to send my kids to the timeout corner so they could take a break. Sometimes they even asked for it. "Do you need a timeout sweetie?" "Yea daddy, I need a timeout"

Answer (score 2):

### Meet the Parents

- Kind of true, taken literally, so on topic
- Short
- Almost unique 3 letter abbreviation: *MtP*
- [Well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet_the_Parents_(disambiguation))

One strength may also be considered a weakness - the meaning with regards to dating may either be considered funny or a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**The Naughty Step**

Very similar to @someshinyobject's Timeout Corner, so the same Pros.

Cons: it could sound a bit like you will be scolding someone if you tell them to go to The Naughty Step